# Split td in two

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to split a TD (table cell) to look as if it were two cells. The problem is that when the cell grows in Height, I cannot make the two divs inside to occupy all the available height. As these cells can grow dynamically I cannot set a fixed height either (that could solve the issue).

**Here's my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  td { border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; text-align: center; margin:0; padding:0 }
  #span1 { background-color: #DDD; width: 25px; float: right; }
  #span2 { background-color: #EEE; width: 24px; float: left; }
  .t { border-top: 1px solid black; }
  .r { border-right: 1px solid black; height: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3<div><div id="span1" class="t">1</div><div id="span2" class="t r">1</div></div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2 2 2 2 2 22 2 </td><td><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 </td><td><span style="line-height:2"><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></span></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is how it looks:**

[image: current table view]

I don't want to see those white gaps in column 3.

Any ideas how to solve this?
I've been fightting with CSS for a while with no luck so far ...

Thanks!.

Comment: And actually splitting the tds is not an option? Then the "3" on top could be in a td with `colspan="2"`.

Comment: You mean, by using colspan and/or rowspan? If that's the case then no, that's not an option. Although I could put whatever I want inside the cells (without modifying the number of columns/rows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should be set the height td height=100%, and  .span1 set height=100% then try to this you can get the answer..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  td { border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; text-align: center; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
  #span1 { background-color: #DDD; width: 25px; float: right; height:100%; }
  #span2 { background-color: #EEE; width: 24px; float: left; }
  .t { border-top: 1px solid black; }
  .r { border-right: 1px solid black; height: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3<div><div id="span1" class="t">1</div><div id="span2" class="t r">1</div></div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2 2 2 2 2 22 2 </td><td><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 </td><td><span style="line-height:2"><div id="span1">3</div><div id="span2" class="r">3</div></span></td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting

```
display:inline-block
```

may or may not also need to add height 100% as well.

Also is there no way you could simply add 2 td's rather than trying to mimic 2??

Answer (score 0):

you can put a table inside that table cell, then that inner table you can do whatever you want, like `td colspan="2"` for the top row, and td td for the bottom row  (this reminds me of the ugly days of table layout, but whatever works for you!)

Comment: I believe there has to be a better way to do it... but, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: no he's right, you'll most likely need to remove all the padding / margins in the table that goes inside but yes this sounds right. common rule of thumb in html = tables are evil and never do what you want them too, avoid if possible. Take any solution someone gives you that will work

Answer (score 0):

I also have been searching for a way to split a TD (Table Data Cell). After reading many posts and after several failed attempts, I finally have cracked it. Many thanks to all who have posted previously, as it is to your credit that I was able to connect the dots.

There are two things you need to have in mind, Affecting Header Row, and Resulting Data Row. What I mean by this is that the cells in the top row [Affecting Header Row] that use 'colspan' directly effect the cells in the row beneath them [Resulting Data Row]. So for example, If my resulting row (2nd Row) must contain split TDs, then it is affected by the row above which uses 'colspan' in its TDs (1st Row). But if the following row (3rd Row) must be unaffected by the 'colspan' from the 1st Row, the cells in the following row (3rd Row) must have the same 'colspan' attributes as the cells in the 1st Row, this prevents them from being split and makes them 'span' the regular gap.

In the image [click the link to see image], I have only 2 columns [2nd and 4th columns] that are splitting TDs beneath them. In the 1st row I use 'colspan' to affect the rows below. However, I don't want the 2nd and 3rd rows split, so they have the same 'colspans' as the 1st row. I DO want to split cells in the 4th and 5th rows [in the 2nd and 4th columns only of course], so to accomplish this, they contain no 'colspan' attributes, which makes them affected by the rows above them which do use 'colspan'. The 6th row is unaffected by the 'colspans' from the previous rows, because it contains the same 'colspan' attributes as the first 3 rows. The 7th and final row contains split TDs because it, like rows 4 and 5, contains no 'colspans'. This may sound confusing, but if you look at the image and try the source code, I think you will be very pleased. I hope this helps.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/12121792@N02/sets/72157651047314439/

```
<table border="1px solid" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="#000000" width="959" cellpadding="5">
  <tr align="justify" valign="top">
    <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="210"><h4 style="color:#000000" align="center">Nothing Special Here</h4></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle" bgcolor="#6E7F8B"><h4 style="color:#FFFFFF" align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</h4></td>
    <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#6E7F8B" width="191"><h4 style="color:#FFFFFF" align="center">No Colspan Here</h4></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle" bgcolor="#6E7F8B"><h4 style="color:#FFFFFF" align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</h4></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gray1" valign="top" align="justify">
    <td valign="middle"><p align="justify">Nothing Special Here</p></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle"><p align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</p></td>
    <td width="191" valign="middle"><p align="center">No Colspan Here</p></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle"><p align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gray1" valign="top" align="justify">
    <td valign="middle"><p align="justify">Nothing Special Here</p></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle"><p align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</p></td>
    <td width="191" valign="middle"><p align="center">No Colspan Here</p></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle"><p align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gray1" valign="top" align="justify">
    <td valign="middle"><p align="justify">Nothing Special Here</p></td>
    <td width="129" valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td width="120" valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td width="191" valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td width="99" valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td width="101" valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gray1" valign="top" align="justify">
    <td valign="middle"><p align="justify">Nothing Special Here</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td width="101" valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr class="gray1" valign="top" align="justify">
    <td valign="middle"><p align="justify">Nothing Special Here</p></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle"><p align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">No Colspan Here</p></td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle"><p align="center">Colspan=&quot;2&quot;</p></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr class="gray1" valign="top" align="justify">
    <td valign="middle"><p align="justify">Nothing Special Here</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>
    <td valign="middle"><p align="center">Nothing Special</p></td>        
  </tr>  
</table>
```